# How to improving speed HLS video with proxy server, varnish? or another way

Tags: nginx, proxy, vpn, varnish

I have 2 servers, A & B.

```
A - Canada  - VPS
B - Germany - DC
C - Brazil  - User
```

B to C - There is a lot of lag, bad connection. 500kbps some times.

A to C - Very good on most computers. 2gbps all speed vps.

B to A to C - Very good on most computers. 600mbps~900mbps.

I use HLS on demand, I would like to know a way to make the connection from server **B** go through server **A** and go to the client in a professional way. Extracting the whole of the connection.

I tried nginx proxy but I don't know if I'm on the right path.
I tried Varnish but I didn't know how to configure it and I don't know if it's the best way
I tried to make the remote disk B be mounted on the VPS (Server A)

Answer (score 2):

What your building is a small private CDN. Varnish is a great tool to build out a CDN.

### Origin & Canadian CDN POP

I would stay away from mounting disks remotely and I would establish a single server as your origin server. This server has all the HLS data that it serves from disk via a web server. This could be Apache or Nginx.

Let's assume this server is installed in Canada and has the hypothetical hostname `ca.example.com`.

On this server you would run the web server on port `8080` and Varnish on port `80`. You could also install Hitch as the TLS proxy and process port `443` for TLS termination.

This server would act as the origin but also as the Canadian Point Of Presence. On top of that the Varnish would also serve as an "origin shield" when other POPs connect to revalidate content.

### German POP

The server in Germany could also serve as a CDN POP and have Varnish installed on port `80` and Hitch on `443`.

Imagine this server being `de.example.com`.

This Varnish server would point to `ca.example.com` as its backend, basically fetching the content from the Varnish server in Canada and also caching it in Germany.

### Routing traffic

In order to reduce latency, you can use geolocation awareness to find the closest POP. Your DNS server could take care of this.

Hypothetically, you could create multiple `www.example.com` DNS records that use geolocation routing rules to resolve to the right IP.

You could for example create a `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` that points to `ca.example.com` if the detected continent for the user is North America.

You could create the same rule that is targeted at South America.

Users located in Europe would have a `CNAME` record for `www.example.com` that points to `de.example.com` in Germany.

And then it's a matter of defining a fallback for users coming out of other continents.

AWS Route 53 is pretty good at this. It's Amazon Web Service's DNS server that support geolocation.

### Relevant setup & install guides

- Installing Varnish: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/#installations
- Installing Hitch: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/terminate-tls-varnish-hitch/
- Route53 geolocation routing: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo